# Angular Js - [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nameFilterProvider <- nameFilter

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Error AngularJs:

I don't understand why I get

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nameFilterProvider <-
>   nameFilter

This code:

**Here my  app.Js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute'])

        .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'pessoaCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '/app/templates/pessoa.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirecTo: '/' });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')

        }]);
})();
```

**Here my pessoaCtrl.Js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('pessoaCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
            $scope.pessoas = [];
            getData();

            function getData() {
                dataService.getPessoas().then(function (response) {
                    $scope.pessoas = response;
                });
            };
        }]);
})();
```

**Here my  dataService.Js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
            var service = {};
            service.getPessoas = function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                //return $http.get("/api/EmployeeInfoAPI");
                $http.get('/Pessoas/GetAllPessoas').then(function (result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result.data);
                }, function () {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
                return deferred.promisse;
            };
            return service;
        }]);
})();
```

Comment: none of your code shows the use of `nameFilter`, you need to find where it is referenced/used

Comment: You used nameFilter somewhere else.